# Can't get user data through facebook OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

We are moving new facebook auth system, however we had some difficulties. Our software gets access_token perfectly but when it tries to get user data over "*https://graph.facebook.com/**me**/?access_token=2213137650421321321|mPvhgRLuSQ_khfggfhfgs*" it fails.

```
{   "error": {
  "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
  "type": "OAuthException"   } }
```

When i try to get data through "*https://graph.facebook.com/**myUserId**/?access_token=275374459176504|mPvZq1AAoA0iUzjRLuSQ_kdRWns*" it works perfectly again.

The main problem is, does "me" work perfectly or am I doing something wrong, what should I do, any ideas?

Comment: App AccessToken vs. User Access token perhaps ?

Comment: Are you requesting a new access token each time your user logs in?

Comment: Access Token is ok, i have tried with different users. And yes, everytime user log in, it requests new access token.

Comment: It sounds like your code is treating **me** as the username, since your authentication token is invalid for that username, your authentication is failing